# live tail (tail -f) of file being grepped

Tags: grep, tail

i can do `tail -f -n20 <file>` to see the last 20 lines of the file, live.

If i want to grep something, 
`tail -f <file> | grep <pattern>`, it will still be live, but will only grep through the output of tail, meaning I am not gaurunteed 20 lines of output at first. (if only 5 of 20 lines match my pattern, I only get 5 lines out of output)

If I do something like

```
grep <pattern> <file> | tail -n20
```

I am gaurunteed 20 lines of output but it isn't live, nor is

```
cat <file> | grep <pattern> | tail -n20
```

How can I see a live update of the last n lines of a file *after* grepping?

Comment: @HaukeLaging that is incorrect. piping tail to grep will only grep out the last n lines output by tail. Imagine a file where the first 20 lines are the word "foo", the next 20 lines are the word "bar", then the next 5 lines are the word "foo". `tail -f <file>` yields 5 lines of bar, then 5 lines of foo, and thus `tail -f <file> | grep foo` gives 5 lines of foo. `grep foo <file>` yields 25 lines of foo, and so `grep foo <file> | tail -n20` gives 20 lines of foo, so they are not the same

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tee` with process substitution `>()`:

```
tail -f -n 20 file.log | tee >(grep 'pattern')
```

This will show you the last 20 lines of `file.log` and then the result of `grep`.

Comment: this isn't working, `tail -f -n 20 file.log | tee` yields the same output as `tail -f -n 20 file.log | tee >(grep 'pattern')`

Comment: Which Distro and which shell are you on? Also check whether there is  actually any output of the `grep` pattern you have given?

Comment: I have confirmed grep gives me output. I am using the example file described in my comment above, and grepping for `foo`. Using:  Centos 6.7 w/ bash 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Note that in `tail -fn20`, the `20` only comes into play at the very start.

`tail` will show you the first 20 lines, and then carry on displaying *all* new lines being added as they come (whether they come in batch of 1, 20 or 1000 lines).

Or in other words, `tail -fn20` is like `tail -n20` followed by `tail -fn+1`.

Here, you could do:

```
{ grep pattern | tail -n 20; tail -fn+1 | grep pattern; } < file
```

That is, do the first step by hand, and then have `tail -f` display all the rest.